# Power BI - Not showing Column Name, just as (Blank)

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerquery

1. I have a table (A) that includes all the 'Companies' in the database
2. I have a second table (B) that includes a specific list from these 'Companies'
3. Linked them in the model by using the unique code
4. I then made a new column in table A that referenced these values I wanted from Table B (`=RELATED()`)
5. Lastly I used a simple IF statement to autofill a new column to get the desired text output, ie. "Diverse" & "Non'Diverse"

However, the table is showing the values I want, but the Report is still showing these as (Blank) – I assume because it is still referencing from Table B and not the actual text of the new column I created?

I just want it to read the table or text value.

[image: IF Statement Code]

[image: Table Results]

[image: Model/Report Results]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the original column and rename the new one, or just use "[Replace Values](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/replace-values-power-query-28256517-f1e9-4dc3-832f-45786e9cf721)" on the column directly.